# How do you deal with multiple locations?

Tags: google-maps

I'm sure this applies to offices with multiple locations, but I am trying to create a site for a charity that runs summer camps. I was wondering how would you suggest I present the different locations?

I looked at gmaps and open layers (they may do what I want but I couldn't figure out how so easily, I don't want to have to enter coordinates because locations are changing often and I want to make it easy for new staff to add/remove locations).  Ideally it would be good to either have a map with markers that users can click on to see details of the location or to list the locations and once they click on it it shows it in a map.

So I guess there's two questions: 1) What tool can help me present this data in drupal 7?; and: 2) What tool can be used to manage the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using GMap + Location to accomplish this.  The site I've been working on involves Apartment Communities spread out all over the place.  I created a content type for apt_community which accepts location data (I only allowed an exact address but you can let the user pick a location on a map).  Then I have a view that puts all the points on a map which I attach to a page.

Check this DrupalTherapy screencast on GMap + Location (http://www.drupaltherapy.com/gmap) and this other screencast Drupal Aficionado did on using GMap and Views (http://blip.tv/drupal-aficionado/gmap-location-and-views-1773822).

Comment: This tutorial is no longer on blip.tv. Does anyone know where it might be available?

Comment: I too have the same question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/108953/26927) Can you please explain in detail? I have already installed above two modules but looks very difficult for a newbie. Since it has lots of settings...